# ranking arbitrary array of objects

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ranking

If I have an array like this

```
var cars=
[
      { 'title':'brand', 'value':'honda'}
      { 'title':'brand', 'value':'toyota'}
      { 'title':'color', 'value':'red'}
      { 'title':'color', 'value':'white'}
      { 'title':'year', 'value':'1995'}
      { 'title':'year', 'value':'2006'}
      { 'title':'year', 'value':'2007'}     
 ]
```

How can I write a single function that would return element's rank.
So for this array, for elements with title "brand" it should return 0, for elements with title "color" should return 1 and so on.
It should not cache or use any mapping table but should determine the rank on flight, so any time you call

```
getRank(cars[6]) == 2 //true for the last element 
getRank(cars[0]) == 0 //true for the first element 
getRank(cars[1]) == 0 //true for the second element 
getRank(cars[3]) == 1 //true for the fourth element
```

Comment: Please explain your problem in greater detail. What have you tried so far? What was the problem with your solution? Do you have a jsfiddle that can demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Do you really wan t color to return "-1" or "1"?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion... mixing grammar rules with math notation is bad

Comment: This doe not appear arbitrary to me, the answers you are looking seem well defined, systematic even?

Comment: Did you get an answer? Were any of the answers here of help? Do you want to share your answer, even give it as the answer to your own question, at least we can all benefit from the information.

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer based on your further explanations

Javascript

```
var cars = [
      { 'title':'brand', 'value':'honda'},
      { 'title':'brand', 'value':'toyota'},
      { 'title':'color', 'value':'red'},
      { 'title':'color', 'value':'white'},
      { 'title':'year', 'value':'1995'},
      { 'title':'year', 'value':'2006'},
      { 'title':'year', 'value':'2007'}     
 ];

function getRank(data, number) {
    var ranks = {},
        rank = 0;

    data.forEach(function (entry) {
        if (typeof ranks[entry.title] !== "number") {
            ranks[entry.title] = rank;
            rank += 1;
        }
    });

    return ranks[data[number].title];
}


console.log(getRank(cars, 6));
console.log(getRank(cars, 0));
console.log(getRank(cars, 1));
console.log(getRank(cars, 3));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/UtFv5/)

Output

```
2
0
0
1
```

Comment: Arbitrary - "Based on random choice or personal whim, rather than any reason or system"

Comment: you don't get it... "like this" does't mean exactly this particular array. I need a solution that works for any array of objects where every object has "title" property

Comment: Correct, I didn't get your meaning as it was not clear from your question. Another update to your question may help.

Answer (score 0):

If it's already ordered (it must be cause otherwise I would really not understand your problem) you could do something like the following

```
var current_index = -1;
var current_title = "";

for (var i in arr) {
    if (arr[i].title!=current_title) {
        current_title = arr[i].title;
        current_index++;
    }
    arr[i].rank = current_index;

}
```

Comment: Don't use for in to iterate an array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Comment: in this case it does not matter :)

Comment: Perhaps not in this case, but even still you should consider safeguarding your loop with ´if (array.hasOwnProperty(i)) {...}´ See "for Statement": http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html